# Calculating difference and direction between two headings

Tags: matlab, derivative, heading

I have a large *array* with values representing wind direction in degrees(0-360) I am required to calculate the instantaneous rate of change with respect to time, using backwards, forward and then central difference methods.

So far I have managed to calculate the smallest angle difference between elements, but I cant figure out how to also establish a direction, ie, +ve difference for clockwise, -ve for anticlockwise.

for example

winddir =

```
80
80
70
70 
60
360
330

diff = min((abs(diff(winddir))),(360- abs(diff(winddir))));
```

diff =

```
 0
10
 0
10
60
30
```

This gives the correct values of difference between headings to calculate the derivative, but fails to show direction **clockwise** and **anticlockwise**, which I need! I've been trying to figure it out for hours and I'm just going around in circles, could anyone help me out?

Comment: You just want the differences to belong to (-180,180), right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is very bad practice to use MATLAB's function names as variable names.

Then, in order to calculate your differences the way your want :

```
myDiff=diff(winddir);
myDiff(myDiff<-180)=myDiff(myDiff<-180)+360;
myDiff(myDiff>180)=myDiff(myDiff>180)-360;
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, this worked perfectly. This is my first attempt at programming and I'm finding its a difficult skill to aquire at first. Thank you again